# Drawing Attention

Tags: discussion

Is it considered ethical or acceptable to add a comment or an answer to your own question (and delete it later) just to get your question back to the top of the list in the home page, for the purpose of drawing more attention to your problem? Or is the only "right" way of doing this is by starting a bounty?

Comment: Worried about [this one](http://superuser.com/questions/738373/lenovo-ideapad-z500-touchpad-not-working-correctly)? :P I put a little bounty on it.

Comment: @allquixotic I saw your bounty. I headed to the Meta site again to see if I could send you a personal thank you note. It turned out that I can't. So here is your "Thank you very much!" I know this comment should be deleted - you might want to delete it after you read it to keep the site clean. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting answers to your own questions in order to bump them to the frontpage would not only be considered unethical: if you repeatedly engage in that behaviour, this could result in a temporary suspension of your account.

Like you said, one way to draw attention is placing a bounty. But if you can't afford one, editing your post and adding new information also helps. Just don't make trivial edits – keep them substantial.

Note that adding comments to a post does not bump it. But comments like "Why no answers?" will eventually be deleted if flagged or seen by a moderator, since they don't really add anything valuable.

Comment: I tried to edit this answer, but I couldn't.  I think it would be clearer if you said " ... would be considered unethical."  Having the "not only" in there indicates that there will be a second more important point after a "but also".

Comment: The "but also" part is in the sentence after that: you'll get suspended if you continue doing it.

Comment: Okay, you fixed it. ;)  The correlative conjunction, "not only, but (also)" should be in the same sentence.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_%28grammar%29#Correlative_conjunctions   Perhaps a question for English Language and Usage ;).

Comment: You're right, of course. Not a native speaker here, mind you ;)